# Flink Sql Delete old state using grouped window aggregation

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

We are using flink sql to build windowed group aggregation.
We are storing the results in the mongo db.
We have defined a primary key with table inserting data to mongo db.

```
CREATE VIEW USER_TABLE
AS
SELECT
window_start WINDOW_START,
window_end WINDOW_END,
USER_ID,
SUM(PURCHASE_AMOUNT) PURCHASE_AMOUNT,
COUNT(*) PURCHASE_COUNT
FROM TABLE(
    HOP(
      DATA => TABLE USER_SRC,
      TIMECOL => DESCRIPTOR(PURCHASE_TIMESTAMP),
      SLIDE => INTERVAL '1' DAY,
      SIZE => INTERVAL '5' DAYS))
GROUP BY window_start, window_end, GROUPING SETS ((PURCHASE_TIMESTAMP));
```

The results are stored in the mongodb as expected.

Lets say a user purchased some items few months back. and never made any purchases at all
in the recent month.
The data for that user needs to be removed from mongo db.

How can we achieve that?

In other words, how can we get deletion of old state at the sink from a grouped windowed aggregation.

+++++ Updated with an Example ++++

```
Window 1:
Key 1 -> Occurs 200 times.
Key 2 -> Occurs 100 times. 
-----------
End of Window 1 in MongoDb sink
Key 1 = 200 (inserted)
Key 2 = 100 (inserted.
-------
Window 2: 
Key 1 -> Doesn't occur. zero times.
Key 2 -> Occurs 150 times.
-----------
End of Window 2 in MongoDb sink
Key 1 = 200 (Unchanged) **(Here we want the key 1 to be deleted or updated to zero. How to achieve this...)**
Key 2 = 100 (Updated)
-------
Window 3:
Key 1 -> Occurs 20 times
Key 2 -> Occurs 50 times.
-----------
End of Window 2 in MongoDb sink
Key 1 = 20 (Updated)
Key 2 = 50 (Updated)
-------
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're only creating a view. A view doesn't materialize, so there are no results stored in Flink's state. You can read more about that in Flink's Dynamic Table explainer at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/concepts/dynamic_tables/

State would only be stored if you run something like a `SELECT * from USER_TABLE` or `INSERT INTO x SELECT * from USER_TABLE`. When doing that using the Window TVF function (like you're doing), state would automatically be purged after the window has closed.

Comment: Followed by the view, i use the following statement to presist the data.

```
INSERT INTO SINK_TABLE
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE;
```
Here `SINK_TABLE` is a mongodb sink.

Instead of creating a view and then inserting in a separate statement, should i do all in one?

Comment: Followed by the view, i use the following statement to presist the data.

```
INSERT INTO SINK_TABLE
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE;
```
Here `SINK_TABLE` is a mongodb sink.

But the state within flink is maintained. But the state is not purged in the mondodb.

ex:
Key 1 - > Count = 200 -> window=1. -> Mongodb has Key 1 count 200.
Window 2: Key 1 doesn't occur, other keys do occur. -> Mongo db has Key 1 count still 200 and not reset to Zero or deleted.. 
Window 3: Key 1 again occurs and this time count = 50 -> MongoDb Key1 updated to 50.

Comment: It looks like you've modified your original question quite extensively: if you want to remove data from your MongoDB sink, you will need to create a changelog stream (assuming that MongoDB also supports deletes from Flink). Your current result is an append-only stream.